# SessionScoped bean behavior

Tags: java, scope, cdi

I'm trying to understand the "scope" of a CDI bean, particularly a SessionScoped.
Please correct me if i'm wrong.

According to this 
http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/cdi-bean-scopes

A class annotated as @SessionScoped is instantiated by the container, one instance per session.
Even though if i inject the @SessionScoped bean at multiple points throughout the application, they will always have the same proxy that will points to one single instance.

It behaves like the HttpSession and i can use it to store states just like HttpSession.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. What is the question?

Comment: Hi, those are the questions in an answer form. Just need to be corrected if wrong.